# How to make a spritekit game appear the same on all iphone models

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm currently developing using an iphone 4. When I ran on a iphone 5, all the edges were out of the view, like the scene was to big for the view. Is there some property in sprite kit that i'm missing that automatically resizes the nodes so that it looks and runs the same on every iphone model or do I have to do something manually by determining what model is being used and then changing the scale of every node? If I have to do it manually, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: You can change the scale mode, but that will either stretch it or make it to where it does't completely fill the screen. Depending on what your game is like changing it manually can be tedious or simple, but that's usually what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you make your game work for all iPhone/iPod models from 4S to the 6S Plus for portrait mode (for landscape, see the commented code). I have used this technique already on my game Chomp'd, which is for all devices. Notice you might have to edit your game to fit this code. Here's a link to the [GitHub Tutorial](https://github.com/jozemite/SpriteKit-iPhone-Device-Ratios) I've made if you need more help.

Here's what the code will do. The code will figure out the ratio of the device, and then it will calculate the area of the screen that is viewable by the user and create a rectangle of that size despite the size of the device. Then, you can use this rectangle to position your objects, menu items, HUD, etc.

### 1) Initialize the Scene

The max size an iPhone can be is 1080 by 1920 (iPhone 6 Plus Portrait). When we create a scene object, initialize it to that size like this (switch it for landscape) and make the scale mode to aspect filled (that means that backgrounds must be at least 1080 by 1920; the background might cut off for smaller devices). You can add this code inside the viewDidLoad() of the ViewController.swift file or whenever you make a new scene.

```
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1920))
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

### 2) Get the Device Values

Next, we want to calculate the ratio of the device and other values, so add the following inside the scene class.

```
let deviceWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let deviceHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height
let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat
let playableArea: CGRect
```

Next, add the following code inside your override init() function. If you do not have one, then add all of the following code.

```
override init(size: CGSize) {

    //Initializes the maxAspectRatio variable
    maxAspectRatio = deviceHeight / deviceWidth

    //USE THIS CODE IF YOUR APP IS IN PORTRAIT MODE
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: playableMargin, y: 0, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    /*USE THIS CODE IF YOUR APP IS IN LANDSCAPE MODE
    let playableHeight = size.width / maxAspectRatio
    let playableMargin = (size.height - playableHeight) / 2.0
    playableArea = CGRect(x: 0, y: playableMargin, width: size.width, height: playableHeight)
    */

    super.init(size: size)
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

### 3) Create the Rectangle of the View

Add the following function inside anywhere of your scene class. Then, call the function inside your override didMoveToView() function.

```
func drawPlayableArea() {
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
    CGPathAddRect(path, nil, playableArea)
    shape.path = path
    shape.strokeColor = SKColor.redColor()
    shape.lineWidth = 8
    addChild(shape)
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    drawPlayableArea()
}
```

If you did everything right, you should be able to see a red rectangle around the viewable area of the device no matter if it's an iPhone 4S or an iPhone 6 Plus.

### 4) Position your Objects Using the Rectangle

Now that you have an object that is the size of the screen, you can position your objects relative to the rectangle for example, to position an object on the top left, you can use the following code with playableArea.

```
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMinX(playableArea), y: CGRectGetMaxY(playableArea)
//You can also use CGRectGetMaxX, CGRectGetMidX, CGRectGetMidY, CGRectGetMinY for your objects.
```

### 5) Screenshots of Two Devices

Notice how the objects added are positioned relative to the view of the screen.
[image: iPhone 6 Plus] [image: iPhone 4S]

If you want to make games for also the iPad, then you would have to initialize the scenes with a size of 2048 x 1536 or switch it for portrait.

Comment: Thanks, this was super helpful for me!! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem! :) I use this technique for all my games now. And at least for me, the best part is all I have to do is make a sprite that looks good for the max screen size because the device automatically scales them down. I try to prevent from using .setScale/.xScale/.yScale on sprites. Instead, I draw them to that size I need.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have 4 options when working with a Scene:

This can be changed with `scene.scaleMode`

Aspect Fit:  This will fit your contents until the smallest of your screen space is filled up.  I.E. if you were in portrait mode, it would fill to the sides, and leave black on the top and bottom.

Aspect Fill:  This will fit your contents until the largest of your screen space is filled up.  I.E. if you were in portrait mode, it would fill to the top and bottom,  and your sides would get chopped off.

Fill:  This will scale your contents in both directions, and will not preserve the aspect ratio of your scene.

Resize Fill:  There is no scaling involved whatsoever, and instead will resize your scene to that of the view

In your case,  the best answer would be Aspect Fill,  this will of course chop off the left and right data, so when you are designing, do not place anything important into those areas.  This also allows you to work with a smaller set of textures, and allows you to scale up, taking advantage of the hardware antialiasing as opposed to Jozemite Apps answer,  which is to make all your gfx super large and then shrink them for device.  Depending on your graphic style,  one way will be visually more appealing than the other.

On a more personal preference note.  I know you said you are programming for iPhone 4, but if you are designing an iPhone only game,  I would recommend you design your scene in a 16:9 format with a scene size of 568x320,  then check which device you are on by simply checking the screen size.  If your height is 480 in portrait mode,  then you know it is 4 (or 4s),  so you set your fill to .ResizeFill, and shift your scene up 44px,  and every other device you leave as aspect ratio.  This will allow the loss of graphics to happen on the top and bottom, instead of the sides, which is probably what you want.  Basically the 5 can see a little more data than the 4, but have the same scale factor.

Answer (score 1):

What we usually do in SpriteKt is to give the SKScene a fixed size and let SpriteKit do the scaling for you on different devices.

So basically we have 2 ways to do it correctly

1) Set scene size to iPad (e.g 1024x768 -landscape, 768x1024 - portrait). This was the default setting in Xcode 7.

You than usually just have/show some extra background at the top/bottom (landscape) or left/right (portrait) on iPads which gets cropped on iPhones.

Examples of games that show more on iPads / crop on iPhones:

Altos Adventure, Leos Fortune, Limbo, The Line Zen, Modern Combat 5.

2) Apple changed the default scene size in xCode 8 to iPhone 6/7 (750*1334-Portait, 1337*750-Landscape). This setting will crop your game on iPads.

Examples of games that show less on iPads:

Lumino City, Robot Unicorn Attack

Choosing between those 2 options is up to you and depends what game you are making. I usually prefer to use option 1 and show more background on iPads.

Regardless of scene size scale mode is usually best left at the default setting of .aspectFill.

You would use the Universal asset slot and/or device specific images. This way you will have a consistent experience on all devices

Hope this helps

Comment: By default no cropping gets done,  the default is .Fill which is scaleing to screensize without preserving aspect ratio.  This means that the positioning will be the same on all devices, they will just look weird